# True/ False: Let A be an n×n matrix. The set of all n×n matrices X that satisfies (A+A^2)X = O is not closed under the matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question: Let A be an n×n matrix. The set of all n×n matrices X that satisfies (A+A^2)X = O is not closed under the matrix multiplication.

I understand that the I have to somehow prove that the set X is closed under the matrix multiplication/or not closed; however, I am not sure how to start working on this problem.

Would you be able to help me get an idea of where to start?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, it *is* closed under matrix multiplication. Actually, if $X$ is in the set and $Y$ is *any* $n\times n$ matrix, then $XY$ is in the set.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am not sure how to start the prof, since X is the set and it is also involved into the equality.
Do I say that since A is in X, then for any n x n matrix C, the equality (AC+(AC)^2)X=O holds?
Thank you!

Comment: The set is not $X$. Call it $\mathcal{A}$ or whatever: you want to show that $\mathcal{A}=\{X:(A+A^2)X=O\}$ is closed under matrix multiplication. Please, remove the wrong “not be” from your text.

Answer (score 0):

You're under a misunderstanding. Let's fix some notation: $M_{n}$ is the set of $n\times n$ matrices. You want to see whether
$$
\mathcal{S}=\{X\in M_n: (A+A^2)X=O\}
$$
is (or is not) closed under matrix multiplication. There is no $X$, it's just a placeholder, and surely the text doesn't say that the set is called $X$. And $A$ is a fixed matrix, and generally $A\notin\mathcal{S}$.

Now, if $B,X,Y$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $BX=O$, then $BXY=O$ as well. So, if $BX=O$ and $BY=O$, then $B(XY)=O$.

Can you finish by choosing $B=A+A^2$?

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you very much for your explanation, my perception of this questions was wrong! I can proceed by showing that the set S is closed under matrix multiplication, given that multiplying arbitrary n x n matrices by X will yield O.

Comment: @Valeri Yes, that's right.